# Ruby on Rails : Sorting and highlighting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the index function in movies.controller.rb file.

```
 def index
         @movies = Movie.find(:all, :order => (params[:sort_by]))
         @sort_column = params[:sort_by]
      end
```

This is the view file.
  -#  This file is app/views/movies/index.html.haml
    %h1 All Movies

```
%table#movies
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{:class=>("hilite" if @sort_column == "title")}= link_to 'Movie Title', movies_path(:sort_by=>'title'), :id=>"title_header"     
      %th Rating
      %th{:class=>("hilite" if @sort_column == "release_date")}= link_to 'Release Date', movies_path(:sort_by=>'release_date'), :id=>"release_date_header"
      %th More Info
  %tbody
    - @movies.each do |movie|
      %tr
        %td= movie.title 
        %td= movie.rating
        %td= movie.release_date
        %td= link_to "More about #{movie.title}", movie_path(movie)

= link_to 'Add new movie', new_movie_path
```

default.css

```
table#movies th.hilite {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

It gives me the following error in the first line of index:

```
Couldn't find all Movies with 'id': (all, {:order=>nil})
```

I need to sort the list of movies by title and release date and also highlight it yellow. But, with this code, neither is it getting highlighted, nor sorted. Where lies the error?

Comment: Can you please include what the params are since you are expecting a sorting parameter?

Comment: Is the list of movies showing up at all? What is the value of params[:sort_by] when you test this? What happens if you hard code the value of params[:sort_by]?

Comment: @ruby_newbie : That's there in the index file. 
:sort_by = 'title' and
:sort_by = 'release_date'

Comment: @philosodad : Yes, the list of movies is showing up and the 'title' and 'release_date' are links but on clicking them, their background doesn't turn yellow. Also, they don't get sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3 or 4, the find command has changed. It no longer takes a symbol as it's first argument (read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find)

The Rails 3 or 4 equivalent would be:

```
@movies = Movie.order(params[:sort_by])
```

Comment: @MissingAshleys great! I'd also recommend ransack gem for sorting: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack should you ever feel the need.

Comment: Hahaa. I'm a newbie to rails. Just learning the basics for now. Shall surely use it if I become a little more proficient!